# get element value of current page in php

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, echo, getelementbyid

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="100">    
<? $id = '100'; ?>
<? $getid = echo '<script>document.getElementById("id");</script>'; ?>
<? if( $id == $getid ): ?>
<? echo 'id equal getid'; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

I want to get a value using getElementById of current page in php but am unable to using the following code

```
<? $getid = echo '<script>document.getElementById("id");</script>'; ?> code can't page load.
```

How can fix my code to get the value?

Comment: I think you completely misunderstand server side and client side

Comment: I think you completely misunderstand on using `echo`.

Comment: `$getId = echo '';`??

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. Not able to use it as you mention.

```php
<?php
$strhtml = '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>PHP getElementById, getElementsByTagName</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="dv1">http://coursesweb.net</div>
</body></html>';

// create the DOMDocument object, and load HTML from a string
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);

// get the element with id="dv1"
$elm = $dochtml->getElementById('dv1');

// get the tag name, and content
$tag = $elm->tagName;
$cnt = $elm->nodeValue;

echo $tag. ' - '. $cnt;           // div - http://coursesweb.net
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the html from inside php you can to use output buffer functions and regex:

at the begining of php you call

```
ob_start();
```

and then use ob_get_contents to get the content of html and use regex to find id:

```php
preg_match('/id="id"[^>]+?value="([^"]+)"/', ob_get_contents(), $matches);
$getid = $matches[1];
if ($getid == $id) {
    echo 'id equal getid';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused. It is possible to pass values from PHP to JavaScript  but you can not pass your JavaScript variable to PHP. At the same time you can't really get an associated value of an input tag within the same PHP page but what you can do is set the value to input by using PHP.